# How to improve screen quality of wine application?

Tags: wine

I have notepad application running inside Wine on Mac.

It looks very poor quality. How can I change the screen resolution to make it look better?

I looked at FAQ and found this. DPI setting. What value it should be set? Is there any setting I need to adjust? [DPI setting FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_change_the_DPI_.28font_size.29.3F)

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you run `winecfg`? the graphics options include screen dimensions, which you can enable and give your screen's dimensions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I tried to set screen resolution in winecfg to 120 dpi and it still is not what an ideal Windows screen should look like.

Comment: not the dpi, that stands for dots per inch, which only gives the system a hint as to _area_ of screen, not it's resolution.  instead i was referring to the screen size setting above that .. http://i.imgur.com/3Hob0Ta.png hope that makes the difference clearer.